# Meteor - Disable autopublish warning

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to disable to Meteor autopublish warning?

I'm just getting in to Meteor again after quite a while and so I'm still learning. I set up a single publish() because I needed it for an onWait in Iron Router. This however triggers a large warning from Meteor:

```
** You've set up some data subscriptions with Meteor.publish(), but
** you still have autopublish turned on. Because autopublish is still
** on, your Meteor.publish() calls won't have much effect. All data
** will still be sent to all clients.
**
** Turn off autopublish by removing the autopublish package:
**
**   $ meteor remove autopublish
**
** .. and make sure you have Meteor.publish() and Meteor.subscribe() calls
** for each collection that you want clients to see.
```

which was actually good info... the first time it told me. However, as I'm transitioning, learning and experimenting, I don't necessarily want to remove autopublish.

Every time I make a change and the server restarts, I get this message, which makes it hard to spot when I have an exception thrown or something.

It'd be nice if there was a switch I could set to indicate that I don't want the warning shown. Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at the source of [livedata_server.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/livedata_server.js), you'll see that `publish` actually takes three parameters - the last of which is `options`. You can use the `is_auto` property of `options` to trick `publish` into thinking that your function is part of the `autopublish` mechanism, which will then cause it to avoid printing the error. For example:

```js
Meteor.publish('messages',
  function() {
    return Messages.find();
  },
  {is_auto: true}
);
```

Note that you'd need to apply this hack to each of your publishers in order to avoid seeing the warning.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go ahead and accept this. I ended up removing autopublish anyways, but for future reference this is probably the way to go while I'm in early stages of prototyping a project.